# how to use slock under Arch linux?

Tags: archlinux, screensaver

slock is installed with xfce.

When I click on "Lock Screen" from the upper right corner, the screen turn black. Hit any key, the screen will be red, but how can I unlcok?

There is no UI for unlock in slock?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that it was just waiting for the password.
Type the correct password, screen will be unlocked.

Comment: Dear god, what a braind-dead and unresponsive UI design.

Comment: Yes, I agree that it is not intuitive, but it is simple logic. The problem with it is that you may wrongly input your password when the screen is black but slock is not active. This can be dangerous when your input page is on-line.

Comment: what bothers me most is that neither help nor manpage explains how it works